# How can I communicate/pass data through different Fragments with Swipe Tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

Hi I have a Swipe Tab Fragment Activity that contains Three Fragments. I created my own adapter that extends FragmentStatePageAdapter.

Now here I'll explain how each tab (Fragments) works.

In Tab 1 and Tab 2, I have a list with practically the same type, when I mean type, I mean they are Symptoms (fever, pain in the eyes, etc.).

Now Tab 3 serves as a tray. Whenever I select an item from the listview in either Tab 1 or Tab 2, I want to transfer that item to Tab 3 and remove that Item from the List where it was selected.

I have tried implementing an Interface but it didn't work for me since I added the fragments on the Main FragmentActivity through an Adapter. MY questions is

> 1. How can I communicate the three Fragments? Meaning how can I pass data between these fragment.

Now if you want to take a look at what I've done for now, here it is:

I depicted this as Tab 2 in my question

```
public class FragmentGeneralSymptoms extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {
ArrayList<String> symptomList;
String name;
String selected;
Tray tray;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_generalsymptoms, container,
            false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    name = args.getString("key");
    tray = (Tray) getActivity();

    new LoadSymptoms().execute();
}

class LoadSymptoms extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        KnowledgeBaseHelper helper = new KnowledgeBaseHelper(getActivity());
        ProfileHandler handler = new ProfileHandler(getActivity());

        Profiles profile = handler.getProfile(name);
        String age = profile.getAge() + "";
        String gender = profile.getGender();

        symptomList = helper.getSymptomList(name, age, gender);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.general_list, symptomList));
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    selected = symptomList.get(arg2);
    tray.respond(selected);
}
```

}

My Tab 3

```
public class FragmentTray extends ListFragment{
private ArrayList<String> selectedList;

public FragmentTray(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tray, container, false);
}

public void addToTray(String symptom){
    selectedList.add(symptom);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.general_list, selectedList));
}

public void removeSymptom(String string){
    selectedList.remove(selectedList.indexOf(string));
}

}
```

My MainActivity which Extends FragmentActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener, OnPageChangeListener, Tray {
private String selectedProfileName;
ActionBar actionBar;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
    selectedProfileName = args.getString("key_name");

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    InitializeActionBar();

}

public void InitializeActionBar() {
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab tabBodyPart = actionBar.newTab();
    tabBodyPart.setText("Body Parts");
    tabBodyPart.setTabListener(MainActivity.this);

    ActionBar.Tab tabGeneralSymptoms = actionBar.newTab();
    tabGeneralSymptoms.setText("General Symptoms");
    tabGeneralSymptoms.setTabListener(MainActivity.this);

    ActionBar.Tab tabSelectedSymptoms = actionBar.newTab();
    tabSelectedSymptoms.setText("Selected Symptoms");
    tabSelectedSymptoms.setTabListener(MainActivity.this);

    actionBar.addTab(tabBodyPart);
    actionBar.addTab(tabGeneralSymptoms);
    actionBar.addTab(tabSelectedSymptoms);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("key", selectedProfileName);
        if (arg0 == 0) {
            fragment = new FragmentBodyPart();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        }
        if (arg0 == 1) {
            fragment = new FragmentGeneralSymptoms();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        }
        if (arg0 == 2) {
            fragment = new FragmentTray();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
}

@Override
public void respond(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FragmentTray frag2 = new FragmentTray();
    frag2.addToTray(string);
}
}
```

Finally my Interface

```
public interface Tray {

public void respond(String string);
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490827/attach-layouts-to-tabs-android

Comment: hi @user2675569, I already attached the Tabs and View Pager, everything is working well. What I want to know is how to pass data between these fragments. Thanks

Comment: Have You tried to use activity to 'transfer' that data?

Answer (score 1):

what I usually do is:

1.- Define the interface. It's done, fine.

2.- Your **FragmentGeneralSymptoms** must have an *initializated* listener. Yuou're that but you forgot to set the listener in the class.

```
public class FragmentGeneralSymptoms extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {
    ArrayList<String> symptomList;
    String name;
    String selected;
    Tray tray;

    (your code)

    public void setTrayListener(Tray listener)
    {
        tray = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        selected = symptomList.get(arg2);
        if(tray != null)
        {
           symptomList.remove(selected); // if you want to remove this element from this list
           tray.respond(selected);
        }
    } }
```

3.- Your **FragmentTray** class must implement the interface:

```
public class FragmentTray extends ListFragment implements Tray{
private ArrayList<String> selectedList;

public FragmentTray(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tray, container, false);
}

public void addToTray(String symptom){
    selectedList.add(symptom);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.general_list, selectedList));
}

public void removeSymptom(String string){
    selectedList.remove(selectedList.indexOf(string));
}

public void respond(String name)
{

// do stuffs!!!!
selectedList.add(new Symtom(name)); // for example
System.out.println("Inside the respond method respond in FragmentTray class");

}
}
```

4.- And last but not least. When you build the fragments you must register the listener:

```
class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragmentList;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        Fragment fragmentBodyPart = new FragmentBodyPart();
        Fragment fragmentTray = new FragmentTray();
        Fragment fragmentGeneralSymptoms = new FragmentGeneraSymptoms();

        // this is important*********************************
        fragmentGeneraSmptoms.setTrayListener(fragmentTray);

        fragmentList.add(fragmentBodyPart);
        fragmentList.add(fragmentGeneralSymptoms);
        fragmentList.add(fragmentTray);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("key", selectedProfileName);
        if (arg0 == 0) {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentList.get(0);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        }
        if (arg0 == 1) {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentList.get(1);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        }
        if (arg0 == 2) {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentList.get(2);
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

}
```

I hope that it helps.